# Make StreamReader.ReadLine() consider \0

Tags: c#, .net, r, streamreader, readline

According to [StreamReader.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this method considers only `\r` and `\n` as end of a line.

I'm reading a file created from a COBOL app, that adds A LOT of `\0` chars in some places. That leads to `StreamReader.ReadLine()` believing it's a very big line, when it's indeed a junky attempt to create A LOT of "empty" lines. That leads to OutOfMemoryException.

Of course these chars are useless to me. The best would be `StreamReader.ReadLine()` just skip them and keep moving.

But I'm ok if it returns an empty string, so that I can verify for it on the loop and skip/continue when it's found. **But how to make `StreamReader.ReadLine()` consider `\0` as `\r` and `\n`?**

Comment: Do you need the lines or can you process every char?

Comment: I need the lines, I must know when a line ends. Whatever, I just made a pre-parsing where I create a new file, excluding all \0 from it. Lazy but takes only 4 min to create.